# Create email template with HTML and CSS with letterHead

Tags: email-template, css, html, letterhead

I'm trying to create an email template with a letterhead.

When I open the email with a computer its working great, but when I opening it from a mobile or other small screen device, it looks awful.

I transformed it into a custom email template with HTML and CSS, and use the @media to perform some CSS on different devices.

well, It's not worked, and I read that Gmail and Outlook not working with CSS style based classes - only with inline CSS - and the @media cant be used for the inline CSS.

How can I use CSS style base on a device screen size using email template?

the use case is that the email template will be sent via process builder after a lead insert.

Thanks.